# C InternetGetConnectedState Loop

Tags: c, winapi, wininet

I want to wait until internet comes so i created a loop with InternetGetConnectedState function.I started program when internet is disabled.Then I enable internet.But still it can 't exists.What should i do?

```
    LPWORD bur;
int abc;
    abc = InternetGetConnectedState(bur,0);
    while (abc==0){
    printf ("zzz");
    if (abc==1)
    break;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try putting the call in the loop , abc will never change.

Also,  you shouldn't assign the result to abc....also, its a DWORD...

```
DWORD abc = 0;
printf ("Waiting for an internet connection.");
 while ((abc & 0x40)){
    InternetGetConnectedState(&abc,0);
    printf (".");
}
```

and then comparing it to 1 or 0 is not really going to tell you anything,  have a look at the flags it can return :-

```
INTERNET_CONNECTION_CONFIGURED
0x40
Local system has a valid connection to the Internet, but it might or might not be currently connected.
INTERNET_CONNECTION_LAN
0x02
Local system uses a local area network to connect to the Internet.
INTERNET_CONNECTION_MODEM
0x01
Local system uses a modem to connect to the Internet.
INTERNET_CONNECTION_MODEM_BUSY
0x08
No longer used.
INTERNET_CONNECTION_OFFLINE
0x20
Local system is in offline mode.
INTERNET_CONNECTION_PROXY
0x04
Local system uses a proxy server to connect to the Internet.
INTERNET_RAS_INSTALLED
0x10
Local system has RAS instal
```

Comment: I wrote wrong code but i edited it  now in the question its working logic like that

Comment: so how can i understand that should i use InternetCheckConnection

Comment: see my updated code, that will wait till it has a internet connection